# Software/Plugin to track browser history

Tags: gratis, windows-7, web-browser, parental-control

Is there any kind of software/plugin which keeps records of any browser history, though browser history is deleted? Or any kinda thing which mail me the browsing history? I want it as no end user can easily identify.

I just want to keep track of internet surfing of my little brother. So if he visited something wrong, I can block it.

Comment: That could be accomplished via a Proxy, which usually logs all access. Just as a pointer for the keyword while waiting for an answer. If I understand [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parental_controls) correctly, something like that already ships with Vista and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/):

- access to Internet usage stats costs [$20/year](http://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/parental-controls/opendns-home-vip/)
- if you create an account there, it keeps a log of all DNS lookups
- allow to blocks access to certain websites (they provide several [predefined categories of websites](http://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/parental-controls/) such as social media or adult)

Comment: Thanks. I have successfully implemented it.